# Wordpress post meta shortcode within quoted text

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm displaying a custom shortcode within a link and for some reason it is not returning the data and is coming up blank.

This is the shortcode:

```
function ss_shortcode()
    {
        $metaidname = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'metaidname', true);
        return $metaidname;
    }
```

It works perfectly fine when I display the shortcode [ss_shortcode] but when I add it within a link href attribute it shows blank.

```
<a href="[ss_shortcode]">Test</a>
```

I've tried escaping the content, and removed the wpautop filter, but still can't get it to show.

Any thoughts / ideas would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: "It works perfectly fine when I display the shortcode [ss_shortcode]"
how you display it?

Comment: When I add it to the content / text editor in Wordpress it outputs the meta value just fine.

Comment: and to show some text from `php` code in an `html` page use: `<? echo $i_want_to_show_this; ?>`

Comment: Using echo with a custom shortcode is not a good idea, that's why I used return instead.

Comment: sorry i dont know how WP works, never tried to get into. just post the html part and ill try to edit it for you

Comment: then u need to store the function in a var ex: `$my_ss = ss_shortcode();` (as return wont show anything unless its assigned to a var)

Comment: the code might look like this
PHP:
   `<?php function ss_shortcode(){//things to do;}
    $my_ss = ss_shortcode();?>`
HTML:
    `<a href="<?php echo $my_ss; ?>">Test</a>`

Comment: I'm sorry but your replies are nonsense / not helpful. This is a wordpress question.

Comment: sorry was just trying to help

Comment: It's working fine to me. Does value is coming from the custom field? What is the value?

Comment: @JoseAlvinRañola - Yes the value comes from a custom field. The value is a number

I have other shortcodes and it seems the only ones that are not displaying within the link element are meta fields

Comment: Can you paste it here the sample value?

Comment: [ss_shortcode] outputs: 6 .... this has a blank output<a href="[ss_shortcode]">Test</a>

Comment: I tried the value of 6 and working fine.
Did you have add_shortcode( 'ss_shortcode', 'ss_shortcode' ); right under the function?

Comment: I did, it's enabled... it seems to be an issue with the get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'metaidname', true);

Comment: @tux That's what I used and working. This tag is <a href="[ss_shortcode]">Test</a> is in the wordpress editor? and displayed by the_content();

Comment: use `$post->ID` rather than `get_the_ID()`

Comment: Hey guys... so I just found out that shortcodes are not allowed in html attributes anymore... [link](https://wphighed.org/2015/09/wordpress-4-2-3-shortcodes-and-the-future/)